# Run autobahn application with twistd

Tags: python, twisted, twistd, autobahn

I've developed a websocket server on Twisted with autobahn lib. Now I want to run it as a daemon with twistd. In case of simple TCP server I would do something like that:

```python
application = service.Application("someapp")  # create the Application
someService = internet.TCPServer(port, someFactory) # create the service
someService.setServiceParent(application)
```

In that example I'm useing TCPServer class instead of reactor.listenTCP function.

In autobahn api reference I found only listenWS function (like listenTCP for TCP server) and nothing about WSServer class.

So my question is how can I get my app work with twistd? Maybe I should implement my own service WSServer class that extends twisted Service class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep.  Create your own service.  Call listenWS in its `startService` method.  Call the shutdown method in the `stopService` method.